# check if a field contain certain value

Tags: mysql

I have a table **project_info**, i want to check if a specific project(**eg project_id =1** ) have a **status** of **0** through out the table and **at least one of the start_date is <= today's date**.

**project_info**

[image]

```
if(above logic is true){
//do somthing
}
else{
   do nothing
}
```

How can i do this in mysql?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT project_id from project_info where 
         status field (contain all 0 
         with no 1,loop through the whole table for project_id =1) 
          and start_date(at least one start_date <=curdate)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think these SQL useful to you.

```
select * from project_info where project_id >=1  and status =0  and
    start_date <= CURDATE()
```

Thank you.

Comment: i don't want to select project if it contain at least a status with 1 value.

Comment: see my update, i hope you can understand what i want

Comment: By using above table can you provide expecting output its better.

Comment: i just want to return project_id, when it's status =0 through out the table, and one or more of start_date <= today's date. but if  status =1 appear even once in a certain project_id then return nothing

Comment: what is the meaning of these (but if status =1 appear even once in a certain project_id then return nothing).

Comment: look at the project_id 1, since it contain a status of 1 in the last row, then if you do the query to select project_id these will not be returned. but if it status =0 in every row with project_id =1 then select this project_id.